# Angularjs applycss for directives

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Developed a simple angularjs application using the code given @ http://gon.to/2013/03/23/the-right-way-of-coding-angularjs-how-to-organize-a-regular-webapp/

It basically creates your header and footer as directives to use anywhere.

The code is working fine but how do I apply custom css for the header and footer html files.

Can they only be applied inline? 
In other words, Can I not refer to an external css.

```
EDIT: Code @ http://plnkr.co/edit/AmvqLu?p=options
Expected: Need to apply style.css to header.html alone.
```

Appreciate you response.

Comment: of course you can use external css files. It's not clear what your specific issue is

Comment: How do I use it? That was my question. When I use the link tag in header.html, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: what does `doesn't work` mean? WIthout some specifics your whole question is far too vague

Comment: Have made a plunker version @ http://plnkr.co/edit/AmvqLu?p=options . When I remove the link tag line @ header.html, it is working. Do let me know if you have any further questions. Thanks.

Comment: `link` tags belong in the head, why can't you just put it there? Is this what you are after?  http://plnkr.co/edit/XOAgvF?p=preview

Comment: Wanted to create custom css for header html. Wanted this for better code maintenance. I won't use any of the styles in style.css for my index.html page.

Comment: yes. The complexity lies when I have the header.html in a different folder and link it to hundred of other html pages as header, I need to duplicate the css file (specific to header.html) in hundred places.

Comment: why are you even using angular then? Use a server language with one template

Comment: Single page app. I get that. Will make it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS files have to go in the document `head`, you can't place them in Angular templates (your header.html file).  Instead, place all of your css files in the document head and namespace your CSS so that they only apply to the sections that you want them to.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/app.css">
</head>
...
```

**header.html**

```
<div class="header"><p>This is some text</p></div>
```

**app.css** *(turn only the header paragraphs blue)*

```
.header p { color: blue; }
```

You can search for object oriented CSS (OOCSS) or BEM for more information on naming conventions for CSS such that rules don't conflict.